# My Android App built by Flutter can not access sql server

Tags: android, sql-server, flutter

I have made an app in flutter with sql server database. I run my app using simulator and work fine there. After that, I make the apk installer by 'Flutter build apk' in terminal, and copy the apk to my real android device to install my app there. When I run my app in my real device, my app can not connect to database SQL Server (2012 Version). Is there any plugins that I should install in my real android device so my app can connect to SQL Server..?? Because when I run my app in simulator or even in developer mode directly to my real device, it works fine in all features.

Please help me
thanks
Heri

Comment: Normally you should be using API to connect to SQL Server from Android, not connecting directly.

Comment: yes, i'm using API actually..  It's all work with simulator and in developer mode, but when i install the apk to real device, it doesn't work.

Comment: log files may be a good first step of troubleshooting.

Comment: sorry I'm a newbie in flutter.. could you please let me know which log file that I should check..?? thank you..

Comment: I have already found the problem, it's in androidmanifest.xml. I add these code in androidmanifest.xml, but I'm not sure which androidmanifest.xml is the right one to add. Because since I'm a newbie in flutter, so I add all of the androidmanifest.xml with these code.. hahaha... and it works..

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />